# Browser warning about non secured resources

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

I know There are other similar links here on stackoverflow, But my question is different, so please don't treat this as duplicate.

My page has no external resources and everything is being served from the same server using `https`, Firefox and chrome is not complaining it and only IE6 and IE7 are complaining. I used `HTTPAnalyzer` and `Fiddler` (used firebug too) all of them are showing no other non secured files. All of the links are `https`, What other possibility makes this problem to occur. Also may be some what related to this question, IE6 on some pages downloading the `jQuery.js` file with some random number appended to its end using `_=randomnumber`. I don't understand that too. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, my best guess is: You are using Flash and haven't changed all the URLs referenced in it to "https" versions.

Comment: @David Dorward Yes, I am using a Flash based charting tool which internally includes other flash files, But I am not controlling it.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to speculate, but when I had a similar problem in IE6/IE7, it was because the app had a hidden IFRAME with NO CONTENT that was being used as a target for a form submission.  It treated this lack of content as insecure content.  Creating a "blank.html" on the server, with just an empty HTML document, and SRCing it to that document solved that problem.

A similar problem I ran into was a CGI that was being invoked, again in a hidden IFRAME, and the CGI was not producing any HTML output ... and was triggering the same error.

As to the randomnumber thing, it is probably to prevent results from being cached.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, [iFrames without src/content](http://ajaxian.com/archives/ie-frame-bug) can cause this problem.  Also, IE5-IE7 [consider javascript:void() insecure](http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/bugs.asp).  I've been fighting this problem for hours and eliminated mixed-content warning messages caused each.

Comment: Hmm, I am having some `javscript:void()`s in my code, let me try.